# awk is not checking if statment correclt its showing all the print lines in the output

Tags: shell, awk

i am trying to write the below code but awk is not checking the if statement correctly

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -S username/pwd << EOF

SET ECHO off;
Set FEEDBACK off;
SET TRIMSPOOL on;
SET TAB off;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
set HEADSEP off;
SET HEADING on;
SET LINESIZE 1000;
SET WRAP off;
set serveroutput off;

SPOOL /tmp/sql_output.xls
select  * from (
select  PROCESS_SRC_STATUS_IND,PROCESS_RUN_TIME_ID,PROCESS_ID from      raptore.tb_process_prod c 
where PROCESS_ID in (116)
order by PROCESS_CREATE_DTM desc
)
where rownum=1

spool off
exit;
EOF

awk '{

if ( $1 == "C")
then
    print "Job J4051 has successfully run for date " $2 

elif ($1 == "P")
then
    print "Job J4051 is pending for date " $2 

elif ($1 == "F")
then
    print "Job J4051 is failed for date " $2

}' /tempt/sql_output.xls
```

---

### sql query output:

### C            20160330        116

### output of the script:

Job J4051 has successfully run for date 20160330
Job J4051 is pending for date 20160330
Job J4051 is failed for date 20160330

ideally output shud be only one of the above lines but script is printing all the print lines as output..please help

Comment: did you try to print `$1` ? what is his value? maybe you don't need to use awk .. you should use standard bash `if` statement

Comment: its reading the output of sql query using awk...normal if else wont work i guess i need to assign output values to a variable so i am using awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a more idiomatic `awk` version will be

```
 $ awk '$1=="C"{text="Job J4051 has successfully run for date"} 
        $1=="P"{text=...} 
        ... 
        {print text, $2}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `then`  in `awk's` `if` clause,

Syntax should be like below

```
awk '
    {

    if(conditional-expression1)
        action1;
    else if(conditional-expression2)
        action2;
    else if(conditional-expression3)
        action3;
        .
        .
    else
        action n;
    }
   '
```

- If the conditional-expression1 is true then action1 will be
  performed.
- If the conditional-expression1 is false then conditional-expression2
  will be checked, if its true, action2 will be performed and goes on
  like this. Last else part will be performed if none of the
  conditional-expression is true.

Modify like below

```
awk '{
            if ( $1 == "C")
                print "Job J4051 has successfully run for date " $2 
       else if ( $1 == "P" )
                print "Job J4051 is pending for date " $2 
       else if ( $1 == "F" )
                print "Job J4051 is failed for date " $2
     }
    '  infile
```

Comment: else if throws syntax error awk: cmd. line:7:       else if ($1 == "P")
awk: cmd. line:7:       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:11:      else if ($1 == "F")
awk: cmd. line:11:      ^ syntax error

Comment: Please check once again